# move event from myservice account to my regular account error occur NOT FOUNND

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Whenever i try to move event from myservice account to my regular account then the problem occur **NOT FOUNND**,everything is ok ,event id, calendar id, destination id, it even move from google interface [Google Move](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move), but from code it says not found, **I Tried to move(last line) after inserting event**

```
  require 'src/Google/autoload.php';
  require_once 'src/Google/Client.php';
  require_once 'src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';

  $Email_address = 'stafftesting@stafftesting-1204.iam.gserviceaccount.com';

  $key_file_location = 'stafftesting-546f9e1a6522.p12';

  $client = new Google_Client();

 $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart");

 $key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);


$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
$Email_address, array($scopes), $key);


   $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

  if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {

   $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
    }
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

  $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Sushildai Event',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
   'start' => array(
   'dateTime' => '2016-01-30T09:00:00-07:00',
  'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles', ),

   'end' => array(
   'dateTime' => '2016-01-30T11:00:00-07:00',
   'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    ),

   'attendees' => array(
   array('email' => 'lpage@unifun.com'),
   array('email' => 'sbrin@unifun.com'),
    ),
  'reminders' => array(
  'useDefault' => FALSE,
  'overrides' => array(
  array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
  array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
),
),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';

$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);

$result = $service->events->move('primary',$event->id,'soorazk@gmail.com');             

printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);

 $service->events->move('primary',$event->id, 'soorazkun1@gmail.com');
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: please check that link ,   https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/move    ,, whenever i try to move event from here it moves, but when i use the code given here, then it says NOT FOUND

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Your question does not contain enough code for us to help you debug it.

Comment: Does your authorized account has write access to destination calendar? To move an event using 'event.move', you should have write access to the calendar.

Comment: I think so , cause its moving from google developer site, or should i get right access seprately

Comment: Yes, you should have right to access the destination calendar.

Comment: If you find a work around or solution please post it here. Thanks

Comment: its working now thanks , i just share the calendar from Destination calendar to service account(from which calendar is to moved) then it worked,   I think it should be like, Service Account share with Destination and Destination share with Service and then only it works

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Official Google Documentation, '4*04 Not Found'* happen in several cases. Here are some examples:
* When the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed.
*  When accessing a calendar that user can not access.

When encountering '*404 Not Found'* error message, the suggested action is to use '*Exponential Backoff*'. Google Drive API documentation has a good explanation of exponential backoff and how to use it with the Google APIs. Exponential backoff is a standard error handling strategy for network applications in which the client periodically retries a failed request over an increasing amount of time.

Here's a useful Google documentation on Handling API Errors and How to implement exponential backoff:https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors